# Connecting sockets over different servers

Tags: c++, c, sockets, client, server

I have it so I can connect my client and server using the same server, but they can't if on different ones. I'm very new to this realm of things and don't understand why or how I would change this. I'm guessing that just having the same port# doesn't help if they are on different servers and there is something else that is needed. Thanks for any help!

Edit: if it's of relevance i'm connecting to 127.0.0.1

Comment: We have no idea what you're talking about. Also, we can't find the bug in code we can't see. Maybe you're binding to 127.0.0.1? Maybe you're trying to connect to your own IP address?

Comment: I am binding to 127.0.0.1! You are like a wizard knowing that. Should I be doing something different?

Comment: Bind to 0.0.0.0 to bind to all addresses.

Comment: Please add the code here, this is not a great way of asking a question!